# Extract a section from object file to separate .o

Tags: c, gcc, elf, binutils, object-files

I have C language, gcc toolchain, object files in elf32 format.

Let's say i have function `a()` that includes call to function `b()`. If they are in a single .c file, the resulting .o file contains `.text.a` and `.text.b` sections, `.rel.text.a` contains reference to the symbol "b" and symbol table contains symbol "b" referencing the section `.text.b`.

If only `a()` is included in the source, then resulting object file only contains `.text.a` section, `.rel.text.a` contains reference to the symbol "b" and symbol table contains symbol "b" wich does not reference any symbols (Ndx = UND). In that case symbol reference is resolved by linker at later state.

**I want** to get the second object file (without `.text.b` section, only containing `.text.a` and symbol "b" that doesn't reference anything) **without** deleting function `b()` definition from the source.

(Background: I have source file containing several functions, I can not edit the source file, I need to separate them to separate object files and later link them back together.)

Commands like `objcopy -j .text.a file.o test.o`, `objcopy -R .text.b file.o test.o`, `objcopy --add-symbol b=0 -j .text.a file.o test.o` etc. end with the following error:

```
objcopy: build/test.o: symbol `b' required but not present
objcopy:build/test.o: No symbols
```

I can't figure out, how to undefine or externalize symbols.

Answer (score 0):

> I have source file containing several functions, I can not edit the source file, I need to separate them to separate object files

The easiest solution is to *preprocess* the original file, spliting it into multiple *temporary* files, which are then compiled separately. Example:

```
// file.c
int a()
{
  return b();
}
int b()
{
  return 42;
}

sed -e '/^int b/,$d' file.c | gcc -c -xc - -o file.a.o
sed -e '1,/^}/d' file.c | gcc -c -xc -o -o file.b.o
```